# How to use session for passing data from one page to another in ASP?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Here I am trying to pass a String variable from one page to another using session..
But it gives an error..
Please help...
Here is my coding

```
//this is for sending
Session["themeColor"] = "Sky Blue";

//this is for retriving    
String themeColor = Session["themeColor"].ToString();
```

Comment: Error 14 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Session.get'

Comment: Are you by chance trying to get Session data from a static method in your page? Because that's not going to work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Web Site try enableSessionState like this:

```
<pages enableSessionState="true">
      <controls> 
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
</pages>
```